# Prisma Error code: 'P2010' Getting unknown model error

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma, crm

code: 'P2010',
clientVersion: '5.10.2',
meta: {
modelName: 'User',
code: 'unknown',
message: 'Kind: Server selection timeout: No available servers. Topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Set Name: atlas-oxeoqy-shard-0, Servers: [ { Address: ac-ezmsl0b-shard-00-00.yiwojeu.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Error: Kind: I/O error: received fatal alert: InternalError, labels: {} }, { Address: ac-ezmsl0b-shard-00-02.yiwojeu.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Error: Kind: I/O error: received fatal alert: InternalError, labels: {} }, { Address: ac-ezmsl0b-shard-00-01.yiwojeu.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Error: Kind: I/O error: received fatal alert: InternalError, labels: {} } ] }, labels: {}'
}
}

route.ts

```
import prisma from "@/utils/connect";

export const GET = async () => {
  try {
    //  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
    const categories = await prisma.category.findMany();

    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(categories), { status: 200 });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return new NextResponse(
      JSON.stringify({ message: "Something went wrong" }),
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
};
```

connect.ts

```
    import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient();
};

declare global {
  var prisma: undefined | ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>;
}

const prisma = globalThis.prisma ?? prismaClientSingleton();

export default prisma;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prisma = prisma;
```

Created model in schema.prisma

```
model Category {
  id    String  @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  slug  String  @unique
  title String
  img   String?
  Posts Post[]
}
```

On http://localhost:3000/api/categories => {"message":"Something went wrong"}

Getting error on
`const categories = await prisma.category.findMany();`